# How to get an external package to compile output for all architectures

Tags: xcode, react-native

## Setup and problem

I have a React Native project that imports a simple external package, HSLuvSwift.

I am running an M1 mac and in order to get the project to compile I had to set the "Excluded Architectures" - "Any iOS Simulator SDK" to "arm64" for both "Release" and "Debug" schemas.

However when building with "Debug" schema it only builds for arm64, see screenshot below.
Building with "Release" schema builds all architectures properly, see screenshot below.

I've tried tweaking the "Architectures" and "Build active Architecture Only" settings to no avail.

How do I force Xcode to build for all architectures even while using the "Debug" schema?

## External Package

[image: Simple external package]

## Build with "Debug" schema

[image: Schema "Debug" only "arm64" compiled for]

## Build with "Release" schema

[image: Schema "Release" all architectures compiled for]